# How can I enable/disable the VCS Commit button, in Intellij using a plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I've already got a working custom Intellij plugin. I can get and check the existing commit message, but I want to be able to disable the Commit button if the message doesn't contain certain information.

```
@Override
public void update(AnActionEvent e) {

    CheckinProjectPanel checkinPanel = (CheckinProjectPanel) CheckinProjectPanel.PANEL_KEY.getData(e.getDataContext());
    if (checkinPanel != null) {
        String commitMessage = checkinPanel.getCommitMessage();
        boolean isValidMessage = commitMessageIsValid(commitMessage);

        // get Commit Button...somehow
        JBOptionButton commitButton = checkinPanel.???; 

        commitButton.setEnabled(isValidMessage);
    }
}
```

*I want do disable the below button:*
[image: Commit Panel's Commit Button]

The problem is that I don't know how to gain access to the button.
I can see it in the debug Variables panel, but those accessors are protected and cannot be used in compiled code.

[image: Invalid Accessors]

[image]

*This is my debug watch (picture above may not be clear enough):*

```
((CommitChangeListDialog) checkinPanel).getButton(((CommitChangeListDialog) checkinPanel).getOKAction())
```

So, the button is there, I just don't know how to get it.

Help appreciated. Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do such things is to implement a CheckinHandler and return `CheckinHandler.ReturnResult.CANCEL` if a requirement is not met. Such CheckinHandlers are ran after user presses the Commit button. See `GitCheckinHandlerFactory` for example.